# Helm set argument failing from Gitlab job variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I need to set a list of values for helm, which works when I run it locally or in the Gitlab pipeline *if it's directly in the script section.*

However, if I pass the list in as a job variable it gets interpreted as a single string.

For example this would work:

```
.openshift_template: &openshift_template
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - $RUNNER
  environment: $ENVIRONMENT
  script:
  - >    
    helm upgrade $RELEASE helm/charts/ -f ./helm/charts/values.yaml
    --install
    --set Hosts={host1\,host2\,host3}
```

This, however would not work:

```
.openshift_template: &openshift_template
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - $RUNNER
  environment: $ENVIRONMENT
  script:
  - >    
    helm upgrade $RELEASE helm/charts/ -f ./helm/charts/values.yaml
    --install
    $HELM_ARGS
    
    
    openshift:prod:
   <<: *openshift_template   
   variables:     
     HELM_ARGS: >
        --set Hosts={host1\,host2\,host3}
```

It does set the value, it just doesn't get interpreted as a list for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out, although I'm still not 100% sure on the cause.

Basically, when written directly in the template's script (or command line) the commas need to be escaped (e.g. `--set hosts={host1\,host2\,host3}` ) but when it's in a job variable you can't escape the commas, it needs to be `--set hosts={host1,host2,host3}`